# setDefaults function for JQuery UI not called correctly

Tags: javascript

I want a page to display the datepicker in french or Italian. To do so i import the datepicker and set it's default.
This is the imports :

```
...
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker-it.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
```

And in the body there is the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it'])
//]]>
</script>
```

Despite it, the datepicker is in french.

However, if I type `$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it'])` in the JS console of firefox, my datepicker is now in italian. 
I think the code is called because if i put a stop on it in the debugger, it is executed.

Why does the code embedded in the page is not called at the right time?

Comment: Add the `$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it'])` after the script tags for the `datapicker` source.

Comment: The datepicker scripts are imported in the header, and the code is in the body.

Comment: Well if you want your datapicker to be rendered in IT, then you have to add localization script before the datapicker is rendered.

Comment: I tried to call the setDefaults before and after the import, it still does not work